# Use the lowest brightness of Intel HD Graphics' power saving setting without changes?

Tags: laptop, graphics-card, intel-graphics

I set the minimum brightness (0%) on a laptop that has an Intel HD Graphics. But, I have found that if I enable power saving settings in the settings of Intel HD Graphics, the brightness can go even dimmer depending on the screen. (For example, if the video has a dark scene, the brightness goes dimmer, and if the video has a bright scene, then the backlight gets brighter)

The problem is that this gradual change is not smooth and kind of distracting. But since the lowest brightness when this power saving is enabled seems to be dimmer than the 0% brightness when the power saving mode is not on, doesn't this mean that the hardware is capable of going dimmer than the nomal 0%?

Is there any way to get this absolute minimum brighness that the hardware is capable of, without the brightness dynamically chaning depending on the content of the screen? I mean, I just want the screen to be the dimmest state when I am using it in a dark environment.

Comment: AFAIK, the power-saving mode works using [PWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation#Power_delivery), which acts like a dimmer _additional_ to the regular adjustment – and, personally, the resulting flicker causes headaches every time.

Comment: Which laptop do you have? You may have a laptop with CABC, context adaptive brightness control.

Comment: It was just a cheap Lenovo laptop, and I have sold it. But I will buy a new laptop, so it would be helpful to know if there is a way.

Comment: brightness is usually controlled like so: `sudo su -c "echo 1 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness"`  but if it is CABC you can do nothing about it, it's hardware.